# React <a> onClick handler is ignored - Google analytics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, google-tag-manager

I have problem with React onClick handler. Despite `e.preventDefaul()`, this link sometimes trigger full reload. I have this code:

```
<a
                href={isInactive ? undefined : item.url}
                onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return !isInactive ? this.props.onChange(item) : undefined;
                }}
            >
                Foo
            </a>
```

This bug is somehow connected with GTM, because when I comment GTM script tag everything works fine. Next thing is that when I stop use datalayer extension for Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/datalayer-checker/ffljdddodmkedhkcjhpmdajhjdbkogke) everything works fine too.

Do you know any possible reason why this problems occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely due to the return value coming from your click handler. Click events will bubble up to all the parent elements if you don't explicitly stop the propagation. If you want the click event to not propagate beyond your handler, you need to either call `e.stopPropagation()`, or return `false` in your click handler function. If you don't prevent the click event from propagating, the anchor element will then navigate to the URL specified in the `href` attribute, which would cause a full page reload.

[Here's an article](https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/) that explains pretty concisely the difference between `e.preventDefault()` and `return false`. It also links to [this article](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) that gives a more detailed explanation of how events are handled.